# React-Native: Can we just do state assignment with out state update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
  class Myclass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onLoad();
    }

    onLoad() {
       this.state.temp = 'Some value';
    }
 }
```

the `state` cannot be set in the constructor itself as it need to be set based on some conditions when `onLoad()` is called multiple times. And when the value is assigned component re rendering is also not required.

is assigning a value to state with out using `setState` good practice? if not, What would be cons?

Comment: `this.state` not update state real time and its not correct way; please use `this.setState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.x = 'something'` is definitely not the right way to set the state. Also, even though you can do it, it is not recommended to perform side-effects in the constructor what so ever as it slows down the mounting times. Refer to: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

So I would recommend you to perform your side-effects in `componentDidMount`. You could do something as follows:

```
  class Myclass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onLoad = this.onLoad.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.onLoad();
    }

    onLoad() {
       this.setState({ temp: 'Some value'});
    }
 }
```

Again, you can't use `this.state.temp = 'some val'` to change states in React because it doesn't re-render the component. You will always need to use `setState` to make sure your component re-renders. Refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) for more information.

Let me know if this has helped, and if not, I will happily answer your queries in comments below. :)

Comment: I con't use componentDidMount() as I have do something before mounting the component itself.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'm sorry that wasn't clear from your question. In that case I would suggest you to go ahead with the `this.state` approach that you have proposed, but make sure that you don't use the `onLoad()` method elsewhere in the code. There is nothing wrong with using `this.state` in a constructor. If you have to use the `onLoad()` method anywhere else apart from the `constructor`, I would suggest you to replicate the code making sure you only use `this.state` from within the constructor and `this.setState()` elsewhere. You can still refer to the links in my answer for more information.

Comment: Sure!. Thank you.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved if either of the answers have helped you. I can update my answer with the contents of the comment if it has solved your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have to set in another function.
what's for?
you have to use setState to change states in not constructor.
anyway, you can use callback function of setState if you need to response right away after changing state.

```
setState(
  {
    temp: 'Some value'
  },
  () => console.log(this.state)
)
```

or just use variables inside the class.

Comment: I get this warning if i use `setState` in my `onLoad()` function ---`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the _class component.`. infact it's preventing the execution